# Is there an Android onboarding library?

Tags: android

There is an [onboard library for iOS](https://github.com/mamaral/Onboard) which provides a nice welcome/walkthrough/tutorial experience for the first app start with just a few lines of code. Simply add title, text and some images you would like to see.

Is there anything similar for Android?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Make sure to include all your requirements *explicitly* (a link as *reference* is fine, however). I'm pretty confident there is at least something coming very close to what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody looking for a nice library which solves the onboarding in a similar way as the iOS library. I found a good looking one after I implemented the complete thing myself. So before you start to do it yourself give a try to [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro)

Comment: Thanks (and upvote). I is quite acceptable to answer your own question, since that will help other in future. Welcome aboard & thanks for the info